# To get current zoom and pan values from svg-pan-zoom

Tags: svgpanzoom

I am using react js, to apply panning and zooming for map a svg image, i am initialising Svgpanzoom instance as mentioned below

after panning and zooming i need the exact values of zoom and pan. How can I get them?

```
let panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#selectorId')
panZoomInstance.zoom(0.8)
panZoomInstance.pan({ x: 0, y: 0 })
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6zskfjte/ please refer to this link. pan the image first and zoom it and then click on move. image is expected to be in same place but it is moving to some other position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getPan()` and `getZoom()` functions for getting the current values of Pan and Zoom.

Comment: Used those methods and applied it to pan but images is moved.